# Output Form To A TextArea And Copy The TextArea Output With Labels To ClipBoard

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, clipboard

Hope I could get some help from here which will help to complete my project.

Using JavaScript and HTML only, I would like to be able to fill out a form with a few fields, once we click the submit button, it should be able to output this complete form with the filled in content to a textarea box or even a div container and then be able to copy that output div container or textarea.

I tried to fiddle around on it on jsfiddle but am no luck on this, it keeps throwing some error. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r9eJ/1/) I was trying to play with.

```
function createIt() {
    var Name = document.thisForm.name.value;
    var Info = document.thisForm.info.value;

    alert(Name + Info);

    outputValue = +Name + Info;
    document.thisForm.outputArea.value = outputValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected your code a bit.
for example: placed document.getElementById("Name") instead of what you wrote.

I have placed a working example in JSBIN , click [here](http://jsbin.com/aYiVegu/1/)

Comment: @Sciption, Thank you for the quick help.
The code works fine by giving the output to the alert(), i would like to see if it is possible to have that output show up on the output textarea box inside the form.

Is it also possible to get the output copied to clipboard with a single click of a button, I did see many options like Zclip and ZeroClipboard, but it is not able to grab the output. any suggestions?

Comment: if my answer helped you then please marked it has helpful answer

Comment: you answer helped me alot, but as I was new here, I dint know how to accept or thumbs-up the answer, just found that and did it, would like some suggestions on the other part if possible... Thank You guys in Advance, really very helpful place this is.

Comment: Zclip is a good solution, see different example in stackoverflow on how to use it for example:
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-copy-clipboard-4-options/#.UFbo1YriYz0

Comment: Great!, this link has surely helped, but not able to get the output to flow into a new textarea. If the text was able to get into an output textarea, I could use zClip efficiently as per the amount of test I tried.